# SQL - Inserting data into one column when other columns are already populated

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a database with 4 columns, 3 of which are already populated (the 4th was added after the fact).

There are 700 total rows, the first of which is called ID which is populated with incrementing integers from 1 to 700. How do I add the 700 values for column4 to correspond to each row?

For instance, if my first 3 rows look like this

```
(1, James, Smith, null)
(2, Michael, Jones, null)
(3, Rachel, Harris, null)
```

How could I make them look like

```
(1, James, Smith, Yes)
(2, Michael, Jones, No)
(3, Rachel, Harris, No)
```

What about if I want to add to the middle of the table (say instead of entries 1, 2, and 3, they were entries 188, 209, and 233)?

Comment: this operation is called `UPDATE`. And update has a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: There is no such thing as an N-th row in databases. Figure out how your Yes-es and No-s relate to your current data and then do an UPDATE with a JOIN.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Answer (score 2):

Either in two separate queries:

```
UPDATE **table_name**
   SET **column_4_name** = 'Yes' 
 WHERE **yes_condition**;

UPDATE **table_name** 
   SET **column_4_name** = 'No' 
 WHERE **!yes_condition**;
```

Or in one:

```
UPDATE **table_name**
   SET **column_4_name** = CASE 
     WHEN **yes_condition** THEN 'Yes'
     ELSE 'No' 
   END;
```

**N.B.** These examples assume that you do not want to leave any `NULL` values.

I would also almost certainly change your `'Yes'/'No'` to a `TINYINT`, where `0` means `'No'` and `1` means `'Yes'`; then you can run:

```
 UPDATE **table_name**
    SET **column_4_name** = **yes_condition**;
```

Comment: I was at first irritated by your square brackets, usually found with T-SQL. And was about to add the 1/0 recommendation too.

Comment: good point, it would be nice to have a standard for pseudo-stuff like this.

Comment: For simple Yes and No where the data is related, that is fine. But what if there is no particular order to what I am adding. For instance, what if instead of yes and no I were filling these columns with salaries. I've got a list of all 700 of them but how do I add them all to the column?

Comment: Then your example was severely lacking! As is your comment.. what kind of list? Paper/Table/Csv? A table can be done easy as pie with `UPDATE ... JOIN ...`. Paper or CSV, I'd probably do some find and replace magic in notepad++ to write out 700 `UPDATE`s restricted by id.

Comment: either you write an UPDATE statement or you write a script that does the update.

Comment: The list is on paper; I'm adding them in to a computer manually.

Comment: @sakau2007 The write 700 updates restricted by id.. I'd use excell.